# HIVE ROW_NUMBER() function creates wrong results

Tags: hive, row-number

When using ROW_NUMBER() on hive tables with more than 1024 rows, the function ROW_NUMBER() duplicates rows with separate row numbers. If use rank() or dense_rank() insteadly, the issue is not present.

Reproduce by using a large table with more than 1024 rows with distinct values and then using a query involving ROW_NUMBER(). It will then result in getting the same distinct values twice with separate row numbers apart by 1024.

```
    SELECT cell
    ,mobilearea
    ,dat
    ,row_number() OVER (
        PARTITION BY mobilearea
        ,day
        ) AS ind
FROM mk.sd_areadetails_tmp;
```

It shows below result with error duplicated ind.

```
cell    mobilearea  day         ind
...
13e98   Tiankong    2022-04-11  1016
86e19   Tiankong    2022-04-11  1017
73a7e   Tiankong    2022-04-11  1018
1dafd   Tiankong    2022-04-11  1019
3e59e   Tiankong    2022-04-11  1020
a3aaf   Tiankong    2022-04-11  1021
0b3d1   Tiankong    2022-04-11  1022
ad190   Tiankong    2022-04-11  1023
994aa   Tiankong    2022-04-11  *1024*
d552b   Tiankong    2022-04-11  *1*
61623   Tiankong    2022-04-11  2
01869   Tiankong    2022-04-11  3
a5478   Tiankong    2022-04-11  4
4c63b   Tiankong    2022-04-11  5
7f90b   Tiankong    2022-04-11  6
6e3ab   Tiankong    2022-04-11  7
294ad   Tiankong    2022-04-11  8
4f739   Tiankong    2022-04-11  9
```

Comment: Your call to `ROW_NUMBER` is sans an `ORDER BY` clause, and that's unusual.  If you add sample data it might better explain what you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: check if `mobilearea`   has leading or trailing spaces or some characters. because where rownumber restarting from 1 is surely be a different mobilearea.

Comment: @KoushikRoy I am sure, mobilearea is same value. If use dense_rank or rank() as ind, the ind is correct.

Comment: hmm, then order by may be the issue. if you can add some order field and  try.